Is determining the existence of a Hamiltonian cycle in a chordal graph NP-hard?
The Hamiltonian cycle problem asks if a given graph contains a Hamiltonian cycle.  The Hamiltonian cycle problem belongs to the class of NP-complete problems. However, for some special classes of graphs, the problem can be solved in polynomial time, for example, 4-connected planar graphs.
A graph is chordal if every cycle of length at least 4 has a chord.
I would like to ask if the Hamiltonian cycle problem is still NP-hard for chordal graphs.

It's NP-complete even on split graphs.
For questions like this, always refer to the graph classes website. Chordal graphs at graph classes.org.
